# pdo issue with try and transactions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

Script works perfectly fine when `$comp_ids` exists in the second query... if it does not exist then the script fails.

My only guess here is that because I am using transactions that it disregards my condition on the second query - `if( count($comp_ids) > 0 )`... is that true, and if so, how can I get around this while still keeping the transaction functionality?  I only want to perform these two queries if they both succeed... or in this case... the first succeeds because the second should not happen due to condition.

Any ideas?

```
//find account based off subscription reference
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    SELECT
        accounts.account_id,
        accounts.licenses,
        GROUP_CONCAT(computers.computer_id ORDER BY computers.computer_id ASC) AS comp_ids
    FROM accounts
    LEFT JOIN computers
        ON computers.account_id = accounts.account_id
    WHERE accounts.subscription = :subscription
");

$stmt->bindValue(':subscription', $_POST['SubscriptionReference']);
$stmt->execute();

//result (can only be one or none)
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// if account exists and it is not a test then update it
//if ($result && $_POST['SubscriptionIsTest'] != 'true')
if ($result)
{
    //inserting into two different tables so use a transaction (if either fails both fail)
    try {
        // begin transaction
        $db->beginTransaction();

        // accounts update
        $stmt = $db->prepare("
            UPDATE accounts 
            SET account_email = :account_email,
                licenses = :licenses,
                fname = :fname,
                lname = :lname,
                subscription = :subscription,
                subscription_url = :subscription_url,
                dtEnd = :dtEnd,
                dtNextPeriod = :dtNextPeriod
            WHERE account_id = :account_id  
        ");

        //bindings
        $binding = array(
            'account_email' => $_POST['email'],
            'licenses' => $_POST['SubscriptionQuantity'],
            'fname' => $_POST['firstName'],
            'lname' => $_POST['lastName'],
            'subscription' => $_POST['SubscriptionReference'],
            'subscription_url' => $_POST['SubscriptionCustomerUrl'],
            'dtEnd' => strtotime($_POST['SubscriptionEndDate']),
            'dtNextPeriod' => strtotime($_POST['SubscriptionNextPeriodDate']),
            'account_id' => $result['account_id']
        );
        $stmt->execute($binding);

        // update computers status because license count changed
        // get comp_ids array
        $comp_ids = explode(',', $result['comp_ids']);

        //if there are any comp_ids then...
        if( count($comp_ids) > 0 )
        {
            //build in clause & binding using selected array
            $prefix = $in_clause = '';
            $binding_clause = array();  
            foreach($comp_ids as $key=>$value)
            {
                $in_clause .= $prefix.':selected_'.$key;
                $prefix = ', ';
                $binding_clause[':selected_'.$key] = $value;
            }

            //set counter for loop
            $counter = 0;
            //zero the string
            $update_cond = '';

            //create the case conditions
            foreach($comp_ids as $key)
            {
                $comp_status = $counter < $result['licenses'] ? 1 : 0;
                $update_cond .= "WHEN ".$key." THEN ".$comp_status."\n";
                //inc counter   
                $counter++;
            }

            //since there are comps then update their status
            $stmt = $db->prepare("
                UPDATE computers SET
                    status = CASE computer_id
                    ".$update_cond."
                    ELSE status
                    END
                WHERE computer_id IN(". $in_clause .")  
            ");

            //execute the changes
            $stmt->execute($binding_clause);
        }

        // if we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown
        // i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction
        $db->commit();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        //error message
        error_log('/fastspring/spc/sub_changed.php: ' .$e->getMessage());

        // roll back the db changes if any
        $db->rollback();

        //failed - send myself an email about this
    }
}
//account does not exist so do something to handle the error
else
{
    //failed - send myself an email about this
}
```

The error... sorry, forgot to add this :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN 1

                    ELSE status
                    END
                WHERE computer_id IN(?)' at line 3
```

Comment: fails HOW? php error? database error? the universe suffers a total existence failure?

Comment: Sorry, totally thought I had added that, but must have forgotten.  Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out the problem started with group_concat in my first query.  This returns the value as a comma sep list, but when I exploded that into a normal array... if it was empty it actually created a key in the array with no value to it.

I had no idea that exploding an empty string would react in this way, but apparently it does.

With that said, I made these changes for the second query and it is working as expected :

```
//if there are computers then update their status
if($result['comp_ids'] != '')
{
    // get comp_ids into an array
    $comp_ids = explode(',', $result['comp_ids']);

    //build in clause & binding using selected array
    $prefix = $in_clause = '';
    $binding_clause = array();  
    foreach($comp_ids as $key=>$value)
    {
        $in_clause .= $prefix.':selected_'.$key;
        $prefix = ', ';
        $binding_clause[':selected_'.$key] = $value;
    }
... and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error suggestions you have illegal syntax right before your `THEN` keyword. You don't say what your computer_id values are, but if they're strings, then you probably are missing quotes. You should do this:

```
$update_cond .= "WHEN ".$db->quote($key)." THEN ".$comp_status."\n";
```

But the above is just a guess. The more general mistake here is that you're trying to diagnose a syntax error in SQL *without looking at the SQL.* It's harder to troubleshoot when you are reading code that generates code.

Instead, you should develop the habit of dumping the resulting SQL, and then the syntax error may become clear at a glance. To help this, I usually create an `$sql` variable to hold my SQL string. Then I can echo it or not more easily.

```
$sql = "
            UPDATE computers SET
                status = CASE computer_id
                ".$update_cond."
                ELSE status
                END
            WHERE computer_id IN(". $in_clause .")  
        ");
var_dump($sql); // temporary line of code, for troubleshooting
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
```

Troubleshooting SQL is usually a lot easier if you're looking at SQL, not at PHP.

---

Re your comment:

You didn't follow my advice above and output the SQL. Here's what I got with an experiment, when `$result['comp_ids']` is a blank string or null:

```
string(114) "
UPDATE computers SET
status = CASE computer_id
WHEN  THEN 1

ELSE status
END
WHERE computer_id IN(:selected_0)  
"
```

Notice the invalid syntax `WHEN  THEN`. It's quite easy to notice because of the double space!

What's going on is that `count($comp_ids) > 0` is true, because the array has at least one element, even though that element is a blank string.

Comment: Yeah, I see where the error is... as I said in my original post, when the array exists it works perfectly fine.  When it doesn't, and this is possible, because I LEFT JOIN these values in my original query... it fails...  the issue is that second query should never be happening, but for some reason it is.  I figured it had to do with the way transactions work, as in, it disregards my condition on that query to run or not.